# How to apply unique constraints using annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations

```
@Column(name = "userId")
    @UniqueConstraint
    private Integer userId;
```

I am using these annotation for entering data into database table.
i want to make userId field unique field. but when i am doing like it it is showing me error `@UniqueConstraints is disallowed for this location.`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "userId",unique=true)
```

or if its an DB generated [ID](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) you can also do this

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
```

Comment: It's not a primary key field.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz so neglect 2nd part of answer and go with first part i.e. `@Column(name = "userId",unique=true)`

Answer (score 23):

Here's an example of how to use @UniqueConstraint:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact", 
  uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "company_id"}))
public class Contact {
  ...
}
```

This specifies that the combination of the "name" column and the "company_id" column will be unique.

Comment: What is the package for the UniqueConstraint annotation?

Answer (score 6):

And this is the explanation of the [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity) version 3.5 for `@UniqueConstraint` definition.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="tbl_sky",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"month", "day"})})
    public class Sky implements Serializable {
       ...
    }
```

and this is for [Hibernate 4.3 example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-class) for @UniqueConstraint